# Dispersion for goldstone bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, mass, dispersion, goldstone-mode

In particle and condensed matter physics, Goldstone bosons or Nambu–Goldstone bosons (NGBs) are bosons that appear necessarily in models exhibiting spontaneous breakdown of continuous symmetries.

These particles may have different dispersion relations:

$$
\omega \sim |\vec{k}| \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (Acoustic\; \;phonon)
$$

$$
\omega \sim |\vec{k}|^2 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\; (Ferromagnetic\;  Goldstone\; boson)
$$

$$
\omega \sim |\vec{k}|^{3/2}
$$

Last example from [Nambu-Goldstone bosons with fractional-power dispersion relations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3365).

**Which types of dispersion relation for goldstone bosons are possible?**